Some functions keep on running endlessly on xTensor, xAct
I was trying to do some calculations to prove a few equations of the following paper  https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.08362 named "Derivation of regularized field equations for the Einstein-Gauss-Bonnet theory in four dimensions" by Pedro Fernandes et al.
In this paper we work with two metrics, the original one $g_{\mu\nu}$ and the conformally related one, $\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}=e^{2\phi}g_{\mu\nu}$, where $\phi$ is certain scalar function.
First, I was trying to recover the equation (16) in which it relates the conformal Ricci scalar in terms of the original Ricci scalar and derivatives of the conformal factor. I wrote the following code in order to do so.
<< xAct`xTensor`
$PrePrint = ScreenDollarIndices

DefParameter[dim, PrintAs -> "D"]
DefManifold[M, dim, {a, b, c, i, j, k, l, m, n}]
DefMetric[-1, g[-a, -b], cd, SymbolOfCovD -> {";", "\[Del]"}]
DefTensor[\[Phi][], M]
DefMetric[-1, gc[-a, -b], cdConf,
 SymbolOfCovD -> {"|", "\[CapitalDifferentialD]"},
 PrintAs -> "\[Gamma]"]

confRules = {gc[a_, b_] -> Exp[2 \[Phi][]] g[a, b],
  Invgc[a_, b_] -> Exp[-2 \[Phi][]] g[a, b]}

RicciScalarcdConf[] - Exp[-2 \[Phi][]] RicciScalarcd[] //
   RiemannToChristoffel // NoScalar // ChristoffelToGradMetric

% /. confRules

ToCanonical[%, UseMetricOnVBundle -> None]

Simplify[%]

ChangeCovD[%, PD, cd]

ContractMetric[%, OverDerivatives -> True]

ToCanonical[%, UseMetricOnVBundle -> None]

Simplify[%]

% // ChristoffelToGradMetric

Simplification[%]

Obtaining the desired result. I believe this code can be efficiently improved by omitting some of the steps and/or reordering the functions applied in each step, but this was my best option in order to obtain the same result as the paper and avoid messy terms involving derivatives of the metric.
Now, my main objective was in fact obtain the same result as the paper for the GaussBonnet term, not the Ricci scalar (which was in fact just an introductory example to the method presented in the paper). This is, equation (24).
First, I tried to apply the functions RiemannDownToRiemann and RiemannToChristoffel to the Kretschmann scalar but these did not work as expected. So I tried to define the Kretschmann scalar and the conformal K scalar by myself, as follows.
Kcd = Riemanncd[-a, -b, -c, -m] Riemanncd[a, b, c, m]
KcdConf = RiemannDowncdConf[-a, -b, -c, -m] RiemannDowncdConf[-i, -j, -k, -n] \
Invgc[a, i] Invgc[b, j] Invgc[c, k] Invgc[m, n]

Having done that, I defined the Gauss-Bonnet term and applied the same steps I did with the Ricci scalar previously,
GaussBonnetcd = 
 RicciScalarcd[]^2 - 4 Riccicd[-a, -b] Riccicd[a, b] + Kcd
GaussBonnetcdConf = 
 RicciScalarcdConf[]^2 - 
  4 RiccicdConf[-a, -b] RiccicdConf[-i, -j] Invgc[a, i] Invgc[b, j] + 
  KcdConf

GaussBonnetcdConf - Exp[-4 \[Phi][]] GaussBonnetcd // 
    RiemannDownToRiemann // RiemannToChristoffel // 
  NoScalar // ChristoffelToGradMetric
% /. confRules

ToCanonical[%, UseMetricOnVBundle -> None]
Simplify[%]
        

but the problem comes in these two steps, where, in my case, the kernel keeps on running non-stop without giving any response.
I understand that the expressions previous to these last two steps were considerably large, but I believe the best way to use ToCanonical function is by expanding everything in terms of the original metric and the conformal factor (and derivatives) in order for the kernel to consider all the symmetries possible.
So my question is: Is there any way to obtain the desired result of the paper in a reasonable amount of computation time? And if so, how can I change my code in order to obtain that result?
Thank you very much.
Matteo.

PS: I tried solving the problem in a different way by decomposing the Gauss-Bonnet term into the Ricci contractions term, the Ricci scalar term and the Riemann tensor contractions term, and try to calculate the conformal transformation for each of one. Though some of the steps were computationally heavy, they were solvable in a certain amount of time. Finally I summed all the terms up and obtain the conformal transformation of the GB term successfully.
